# Is $x^{0.5}\cdot x^{0.5}$ a polynomial function on the domain for which it defines the same function as $x^1$.

Tags: polynomials

Is it right to say for $x>0$ it is a polynomial function? I am using the same reasoning why a constant is a polynomial e.g, $1$ defines the same function as $1x^0$ on whatever domain, so $1$ is a polynomial function defined on whatever domain you are working on.

Comment: It’s true even for negative value because you’ll have an imaginary unit on both sides, and we have that $i^2=-1$

Comment: Thanks, but i am using the traditional definition of x^1/2 which is only defined for x>0. it is possible to define x^1/2 for any complex number in a way which is consistent with x^1, but i was wondering whether it is a polynomial on the normal definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finicky details like this are probably best settled based on context more than anything. There are definite calls for working with polynomials on restricted domains, for example the [Stone-Weierstrass Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem). On the other hand, theorems such as the [Fundamental Theorem of Algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra) would not work if polynomials were permitted to be defined over only part of the space.

So, in short, check back on your notes, wherever polynomials are defined (as hopefully they have been). That will tell you the definition you're supposed to be working with.

Comment: Checking the definitions is always #1 advice. But if we start questioning the definitions themselves, the OP might want to take a look at the philosophical rambling after the edit: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2362550/unique-continuous-extension-of-rational-function

Comment: when you say "if polynomials were permitted to be defined over only part of the space", do you mean over part of the space for which x^1 is defined? because its possible to define f(x)=x^0.5*x^0.5 for x any complex number

Comment: I was trying to address what I see to be the core of your question: is a function, defined on a proper subset of $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$, that agrees with a polynomial over its domain, a polynomial itself? Considered as a real function, $x^{0.5} \cdot x^{0.5}$ is defined for $x \ge 0$, and thus is not defined on the "whole space" $\mathbb{R}$. While changing to $\mathbb{C}$ fixes this particular issue, I still think the question still stands and is worth answering, even if the answer is "check your definitions".